# How to find a file without specific path

Tags: c#

Im trying to send a compressed file with an email.
So the step is :
1. Compressed the file that we want to.
2. Send the email in outlook, with the attachment from the compressed file.

My problem is when the application try to search for the compressed file, it wont find because my path didnt right.
Here's the code

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                //zip.UseUnicodeAsNecessary = true;
                zip.AddDirectory(@"Y:\"+tglskrg+"\\Result");
                zip.Save(@"C:\Users\Desktop\"+tglskrg+".zip");
            }

            string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), tglskrg + ".zip");
//Send email code(which basicly work);
```

my problem is , the file is saved in desktop

the actual result is , when the apps try to search for the file, the apps look in the path directory which from the code i write, the path is in the Debug folder from the application.

Anyone can help ? or maybe where did i do wrong?

Thankyou

Comment: in this case, consider a registry setting or environment variable to set / get a common value for data directory.  both the save and load functions would use that value to pick a directory.

Comment: Why not just use the same path in the `Save` method and the `Path.Combine` method? I don't understand why you're doing it differently in each and then wondering why they're not the same?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am not understanding your question; but, if you want to refer to the desktop folder, use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)`.

For example, you are trying to save your zip file to the desktop,

change this:

`zip.Save(@"C:\Users\Desktop\"+tglskrg+".zip");`

to this:

`zip.Save(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), tglskrg + ".zip"));`